# Modern ui current navigation default expandable

Tags: sharepoint-online, navigation, modern-experience, quick-launch

Is possible to expand Modern UI current navigation by default despite of clicking arrows icons  to expand it and collapsed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is **not possible** in SharePoint Online Modern experience by using **OOTB functionalities**.

You can read more about it on SharePoint Tech Community:
 [Can you set the Quick Launch Menu as to default as collapsed with Modern Pages?](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/SharePoint/Can-you-set-the-Quick-Launch-Menu-as-to-default-as-collapsed/m-p/75657).

Also, I found one UserVoice suggestion on SharePoint UserVoice, you can vote on it:
 [Left menu/submenu expand and/or collapse default behavior setting](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/34392373-left-menu-submenu-expand-and-or-collapse-default-b).